# Using mode formats in session.save_path Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm facing a problem using the session library in Codeigniter. On [this page](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) it specifically says

> To be more specific, it doesn’t support PHP’s directory level and mode formats used in session.save_path, and it has most of the options hard-coded for safety. Instead, only absolute paths are supported for $config['sess_save_path'].

Now what I want is to create session files with permissions 777. I've set the session_save_path in php.ini to `0;0777;/home/sessions/`. This is overwritten by the local value by Codeigniter to `/home/sessions`. How can I force Codeigniter to create these session files with 777 permissions, as it doesn't support this in the config file.

Please don't mind about the 777 permissions on session files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About changing the default dir permissions which ic 0700 by default, i don't recommend this at all cause you'll have to change the core system files which is a very bad practice but if you must have a look at `Session_files_driver.php` and change `mkdir($save_path, 0700, TRUE)` to `mkdir($save_path, 0777, TRUE)` if you must and if it doesn't exist already with 0777 permission... btw, i think its way better to use db to store sessions.

Comment: No, CI saves session files wherever you tell it to, which can be anywhere on the system, including outside `APPPATH`.

Comment: I talked about the defaults here; and i guess its better this way to save in in the APPPATH in your writable dir.

Comment: [There is no default](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php). What is "better" depends entirely on each project, and personal preference. In any case, you might want to update your answer to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing some config setting you can save your session as per your set location

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

in $config['sess_save_path'] mention your path where you want to store your session file.